# Showing pre-selected data in dropdown based on object

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="object.item" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in list" />
```

This is for showing pre-selected data in dropdown , based on item.id.Here, item.name will be shown and pre-selected data will be shown based on id.

I want to show preselected data based on object like-

```
<select ng-model="object.item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in list" />
```

its not working.Is it possible to do so???

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just need to make sure that `object.item` is one of the items of the list. It must not **look** like one of these items. It must **be** one of these items. If you posted your code, we could explain why it fails, and help you fix it.

Comment: Check this one : ng-options="item as item.name for item in list track by item.id".

Comment: Thank u @JB Nizet...I solved  it..... " It must not look like one of these items. It must be one of these items." ...this statement helped me ...i was using different objects.